# Compiling Ruby 1.9.1-p129 on HPUX

Tags: ruby, hp-ux

I am trying to compile Ruby on HPUX but get the following:

```
cc: "transcode.c", line 1489: error 1588: "SIZE_MAX" undefined.
cc: "transcode.c", line 1489: error 1563: Expression in if must be scalar.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with SIZE_MAX being undefined using aCC compiler without the C99 flag. Using this environment option in the ./configure got me past it, but I'm hitting other problems later on (miniruby compiles and links, but throws a Bus Error when the make process continues :-/). Does this help you build?

```
CC="cc -AC99" CPPFLAGS="-D_HPUX_SOURCE" ./configure
```

Answer (score 0):

What HPUX and compiler version?

If I remember correctly SIZE_MAX is only available if you use c99 compiler and include stdint.h (not limits.h).